# Trying to remove duplicates without messing up the border

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to remove duplicates without messing up the border. I have some code already written, but when I try it, it either messes up the border or clears data out of its range.

I just want to compare the list of drawings that I have without going out of the specified range or messing up the border

Sub DelDupl()

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A13:F305")

Range("A13").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3, 4), Header:=xlYes


With rng.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Color = vbBlack
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
End Sub
```

I would like to compare the document identifier column with the sheet column, if there is a match, then to delete the respective row.

I have attached a picture below. I just want to compare data starting at row 14. When I run my code it will also delete the "Digital file" text seen in row 11.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Program1()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With Sheets("Sheet1")
  Lastrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

' for B column and C Column
Set Rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(14, 2), ws.Cells(Lastrow, 3))
Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your RemoveDuplicates is based on columns C and D but you need to get rid of CurrentRegion and define the range.

```
With Range(Cells(13, "A"), Cells(rows.Count, "A").end(xlup))
    .resize(.rows.count, 6).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3, 4), Header:=xlYes
End With

'depending on what is below row 37, the range might have to be defined this way (although the former is preferable)
With Range(Cells(13, "A"), Cells(13, "A").end(xldown))
    .resize(.rows.count, 6).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3, 4), Header:=xlYes
End With
```

CurrentRegion is the 'data island' that extends in all directions until it meets a fully blank column, a fully blank row or the extents of the worksheet. The 'digital island' located around A13 extends at least as high as row 8 in your image.

A CurrentRegion can be tested by selecting a cell and tapping Ctrl+A once.